# Using group-starting-with to group a specific pattern of records

Tags: xslt

I have a very specific requirement to group employee's leave where the days are consecutive and the durations are half days. This is in order to merge them into a full value where the leave is worked on a nightshift. The complexity comes from the fact that no more than 2 consecutive days should be merged in a group.

Example XML

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/WFM_Future_Leave_Report">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Partner_ID>11111111</wd:Partner_ID>
            <wd:unit_id>001</wd:unit_id>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Partner_ID>80710042</wd:Partner_ID>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-06-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-07-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-08-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-09-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>0</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>1</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-10-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-11-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-12-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
            <wd:Effective_Date>2021-09-13-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
            <wd:Eligible>1</wd:Eligible>
            <wd:Duration>0.5</wd:Duration>
            <wd:Status wd:Descriptor="A">
            </wd:Status>
        </wd:Time_Off_Details_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

And the XSLT I’ve been playing around with, I am aware that this will group the leaves where there is a break in the effective dates so is not at all doing what I want it to.

```
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/WFM_Future_Leave_Report"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Time_Off_Details_group[wd:Eligible = '1' and wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor = 'A']"       
            group-starting-with="*[not(xs:date(wd:Effective_Date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::*[1]/wd:Effective_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))]">      
                <xsl:value-of select="../wd:Partner_ID" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../wd:Worker_group/wd:unit_id"/>  
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/format-date(wd:Effective_Date,'[D1]/[M01]/[Y0001]')" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:Duration)"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>NIGHTSHIFTLOGIC</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="match_text" match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Eligible = ‘1’ flags the duration is 0.5 and Status = ‘A’ filters out only approved leave)

In this example the desired output would be:

```
11111111,001,06/09/2021,1,A
11111111,001,08/09/2021,0.5,A
11111111,001,09/09/2021,1,A
11111111,001,10/09/2021,1,A
11111111,001,12/09/2021,1,A
```

This is because the 0.5 durations on 06/09 and 07/09 combine to a full day. The next consecutive day should not be considered in the first group as it has no following 0.5 day duration instance and should be output independently. Similarly where a full day duration exists on 09/09 this needs to be output as is. The grouping begins again on the next 0.5 duration entry on 10/09 to be combined with 11/09 which outputs another full day and then again for the next two consecutive effective dated entries.

Comment: An example XML file would make it much easier to reason about, and be able to suggest solutions. Is the only criteria to group dates by two if they are consecutive? For instance if the dates were 1/12, 3/12 (no February) would you expect them to be grouped?

Comment: Which processor, which tool are you using? With XQuery's tumbling window and the various variables the condition might be easier to express than with XSLT 2/3's group-starting-with. And of course it would help if you showed your XML input structure and the attempt you have made in XSLT with group-starting-with.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `xsl:iterate` for this, rather than `xsl:for-each-group`. It gives you more flexibility in deciding the conditions to apply when deciding to add the next item to an existing group or to start a new group. Use an iteration parameter to accumulate the contents of the current group, then when you decide to start a new group, process the value of that parameter and reset it to an empty sequence for the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will read up but I'm in no way familiar with the iterate instruction, any suggestions or a generic example would be greatly appreciated! J

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 4 in SaxonCS with `break-when` on the `for-each-group` seems to do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="4.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/WFM_Future_Leave_Report"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/WFM_Future_Leave_Report"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:extract-date" as="xs:date">
    <xsl:param name="date" as="element(Effective_Date)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$date => substring(1, 10) => xs:date()"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Time_Off_Details_group" break-when="sum($group/Duration) = 1 and count($group) = (1, 2) or sum(($group, $next)!Duration) gt 1">
      <xsl:value-of
        select="..!Worker_group!(Partner_ID, unit_id), 
                Effective_Date => mf:extract-date() => format-date('[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]'), 
                sum(current-group()/Duration), 
                Status/@wd:Descriptor"
        separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although so far the condition I have used just checks the `sum` and the number of items (e.g. not more than 2) in each group, it doesn't look at the dates as at least in the sample input there is a continuous sequence of dates incrementing by 1 day.

Or, if you use Saxon, you can also use XQuery and the tumbling window clause

```
declare namespace wd = "urn:com.workday.report/WFM_Future_Leave_Report";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

for $re in wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry
for tumbling window $days in $re/wd:Time_Off_Details_group
start $d1 at $sp when true()
only end $d2 at $ep next $nd when 
  (xs:date($d2/wd:Effective_Date/substring(., 1, 10)) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))
  = xs:date($d1/wd:Effective_Date/substring(., 1, 10)) and $ep - 1 = $sp
  and sum(($d1, $d2)!wd:Duration) = 1
  or $d1/wd:Duration = 0.5 and $nd/wd:Duration > 0.5
  or $d1/wd:Duration = 1
  
return string-join(
    (
      $days[1]/../wd:Worker_group/(wd:Partner_ID, wd:unit_id),
      $days[1]/wd:Effective_Date/substring(., 1, 10),
      sum($days/wd:Duration)
    ),
    ','
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using SaxonEE, when trying the first example I receive:

Exactly one of the attributes group-by, group-adjacent, group-starting-with, and group-ending-with must be specified

I've added the attribute and the values are merging into one total of 4.5.

Comment: In the Java world and with Saxon EE and XSLT,  I think you need to wait for the release of Saxon 11 to run that code. The XQuery code, on the other hand, runs with Saxon 10 or 9.9.